# How to make only color part of the div background?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am trying to make something like this: [image]
I got most of it down, but I am having trouble with the yellow rectangle that goes along the screen in the background. This is what it currently looks like:
[image]

As you can see, the rectangles are not the same height because the left and right image have different heights. I know that I can hardcode a fixed value so that the rectangle will be the same height, but I would rather have something responsive, like 'height: 80%' in this case.

I attempted trying to make the div,s containing the rectangle and image, fill up the rest of the parent div using flexbox, but I just made the problem worse.

```html
<div class="justify-content-center row row-cols-4" style="display: flex;">
  <div class="col" style="padding: 0px; align-self: flex-end;">
    <div style="position: relative;">
      <img src="https://cdn.contrastly.com/wp-content/themes/contrastly-v9/images/anthropics-portraitpro.png" style="width: 70%;"></img>
      <div style="background-color: rgb(253, 221, 57); height: 80%; width: 100%; z-index: -1; position: absolute; bottom: 0px;">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="align-self: flex-end;">
      <h3 style="font-weight: 700; font-size: calc(12px + 0.5vw); margin-bottom: 0px;">President</h3>
      <p style="font-weight: 300; font-size: calc(12px + 0.3vw); margin-bottom: 0px;">Name Goes Here</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col" style="padding: 0px; align-self: flex-end;">
    <div style="position: relative;">
      <img src="https://assets.grooveapps.com/images/5fff4a731d2cfa006f386042/1624073591_Professional-Headshots-Portraits-by-Jared-Wolfe-Alexandria-VA-Portrait-Studio-Testimonial-01.png" style="width: 70%;"></img>
      <div style="background-color: rgb(253, 221, 57); height: 80%; width: 100%; z-index: -1; position: absolute; bottom: 0px;">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="align-self: flex-end;">
      <h3 style="font-weight: 700; font-size: calc(12px + 0.5vw); margin-bottom: 0px;">Vice President</h3>
      <p style="font-weight: 300; font-size: calc(12px + 0.3vw); margin-bottom: 0px;">Name Goes Here</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: use [linear-gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/linear-gradient())

Comment: Put the background color on the **parent** of the cards not the cards themselves and, as mentioned above, use a linear gradient

Comment: use linear-gradient and put the `background` on parent element. It would create a uniform yellow background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A gradient applied to the image can do the job. Adjust the `100px` like you want

```css
img {
  background: linear-gradient(yellow 0 0)bottom/100% 100px no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="justify-content-center row row-cols-8" style="display: flex;">
    <div class="col" style="padding: 0px; align-self: flex-end;">
      <div style="position: relative;">
        <img src="https://cdn.contrastly.com/wp-content/themes/contrastly-v9/images/anthropics-portraitpro.png" style="width: 70%;">
      </div>
      <div style="align-self: flex-end;">
        <h3 style="font-weight: 700; font-size: calc(12px + 0.5vw); margin-bottom: 0px;">President</h3>
        <p style="font-weight: 300; font-size: calc(12px + 0.3vw); margin-bottom: 0px;">Name Goes Here</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col" style="padding: 0px; align-self: flex-end;">
      <div style="position: relative;">
        <img src="https://assets.grooveapps.com/images/5fff4a731d2cfa006f386042/1624073591_Professional-Headshots-Portraits-by-Jared-Wolfe-Alexandria-VA-Portrait-Studio-Testimonial-01.png" style="width: 70%;">
      </div>
      <div style="align-self: flex-end;">
        <h3 style="font-weight: 700; font-size: calc(12px + 0.5vw); margin-bottom: 0px;">Vice President</h3>
        <p style="font-weight: 300; font-size: calc(12px + 0.3vw); margin-bottom: 0px;">Name Goes Here</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! but do you know how to make 80% instead of 100px work? Because ideally I want it to be responsive

Comment: @inquisitivemongoose 80% of what? both your image don't have the same height so you cannot rely on percentage